# Can't install azure cli on centos

Tags: azure, centos7, azure-cli

I am trying to install azure-cli on centos 7 box. I am getting this error repeatedly

Error: Package: azure-cli-2.0.80-1.el7.x86_64 (azure-cli)
           Requires: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I tried to execute both commands but none of these worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Acturally, Azure CLI requires `python3`, it's even an executable Python package [`azure-cli`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/) which you can find in PyPI.org. So please make sure there is a Python 3 runtime installed in your CentOS 7.

If you want to fix your issue manually, you can try to download and install the related rpm package for `Libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)` from https://pkgs.org/download/libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit), as the figure below.

[image]

However, the best way is to follow the offical tutorial [`Install Azure CLI with yum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest) to install it in CentOS 7.

Otherwise, the other solution is as below to directly install its python package via `pip`.

1. Please check whether the Python 3 runtime had been installed in CentOS 7 via command `python3 -V` or `python -V` to see the Python version or system will remind you to install it.
2. Please check whether the `pip` or `pip3` command for Python 3 runtime had been installed via `pip3 -V` or `pip -V` to see the `pip` version or system will remind you to install it.
3. Completed the two steps above, you can easily to install `azure-cli` via command `sudo pip3 install azure-cli` or `sudo pip install azure-cli`, it will help to install `azure-cli` to the system path, then you can try to use it via `az --version`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it by mentioning the repo/package URL

> sudo yum install https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli/azure-cli-2.38.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

packages can be found here https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli/